# Why is $\cos \sqrt z$ entire but $\sin \sqrt{z}$ isn't?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, entire-functions

I've been trying to formulate a way of comparing these two functions, in order to find out why the function $\sin \sqrt z$ is not entire, but I couldn't find a good way of doing that. What I tried so far:

- I wrote the series of both functions:
  \begin{align}\cos(\sqrt{z})&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(2n)!}\\
  \sin(\sqrt{z})&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^n\cdot\sqrt{z}}{(2n+1)!}\end{align}
- The $e$ version:
  \begin{align}\cos(\sqrt{z})&=\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}}+e^{-i\sqrt{z}}}{2}\\
  \sin(\sqrt{z})&=\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}}-e^{-i\sqrt{z}}}{2i} ,\end{align}

but they didn't help me on solving the problem. How could I progress from here? I could not find a way of writing Cauchy-Riemann equations for $\cos$ or $\sin$.

Comment: Because the series for $\cos\sqrt{z}$ has no pure $\sqrt{z}$ (which is not analytical), only $z$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You almost formatted your question perfectly, which we appreciate (especially from users inexperienced with latex or mathjax). Your exponents hadn't been displaying correctly. This is because `e^ix` renders as $e^ix$ --- mathjax only interprets the first symbol after `^` as the exponent. To fix this, I added braces: `e^{ix}` yields $e^{ix}$. Good luck!

Comment: $\sqrt{z}$ involves a choice since there two complex numbers $w$ such that $w^2 = z$. Unfortunately it is impossible to make choices such that we get a holomorphic function $\sqrt{\phantom{X}} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Hence your question does not make much sense.

Comment: Notice that the series representation of $\sin \sqrt{z}$ contains nonintegral powers of $z$, so it is not a power series in $z$---this is the key difference between the two functions here.

Comment: @PaulFrost: $\sqrt z$ denote the square root with argument in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, so the question makes sense.

Comment: @idm This is not an established convention. So the OP has to specify the meaning of $\sqrt z$ if the question has to make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I think this convention is as establish as $\sqrt{4}=2$ and not $-2$... but maybe for you it's not the case ? [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) seem to agree...

Comment: Here is a way of thinking about the question without reference to a square root function. Let $g(z)$ be a holomorphic function. You want to know when there is another holomorphic function $h(z)$ with $g(z) = h(z^2)$. The answer is that this exists iff $g(z)$ is even.

Comment: @hunter I think your comment should be an official answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy After some contemplation I came to the conclusion that the following is true. Let $\sqrt{\phantom{x}} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be **any** function such that $(\sqrt{z})^2 = z$ for all $z$. Then $\cos(\sqrt{z})$ is an entire function. For $\sin$ there does not exist a function $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sin(\sqrt{z})$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @PaulFrost That is true. See the comment by user hunter for a general fact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Nevertheless, as you said in a previous comment: The OP has to specify the meaning of $\sqrt{z}$. The question as it is leads to confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Suppose $F(z) := f(\sqrt{z})$ is analytic at $z = 0$ for some choice of branch cut of $\sqrt{\cdot}$, say, $F(w)$ has power series $$F(w) \sim a_0 + a_1 w + a_2 w^2 + \cdots$$ at $w = 0$. What is the power series of $f(w) = F(w^2)$ at $w = 0$?

> **Additional hint** We have $$f(w) \sim a_0 + a_1 w^2 + a_2 w^4 + \cdots .$$

This shows that not only is $\sin \sqrt{z}$ not entire, it's not analytic in any neighborhood of $z = 0$ (for any choice of branch cut).

Comment: What do you mean by : "for some branch cut of $\sqrt\cdot $ ? $\sqrt z$ denote the square root of $z$ with argument in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: If you're not familiar with branch cuts yet, feel free to disregard that phrase---the answer applies when using the particular convention you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Given any argument $z$, there are exactly two values for the square root, $w$ and $-w$.  If the sine of $w$ equals the sine of $-w$ for all $z$, then the two different possible values for the square root of $z$ lead to only a single value of the sine and thus no branch cut is required.  But, if $w$ and $-w$ give different sines for any $z$, then there must be a branch cut to separate the two sine values therefore you can't have an entire function.

It turns out this doesn't work because $\sin (-w)=-\sin w$ and thus $\ne \sin w$ except where the sine value happens to be zero.  We are forced to accept branch cuts between the zeroes of $\sin w$, meaning $w=\sqrt{z}$ is a multiple of $\pi$ and $z$ itself us a multiple of $\pi^2$.  Can you diagram a relatively simple choice for the needed branch cuts In the complex plane?

Now try it with the cosine function using the same reasoning above, but there is one little difference.  Cosine is an even function, not odd, so $\cos (-w)=+\cos w$ instead of $-\cos w$.  How does that change the rest of your conclusions above for the cosine function, as opposed to the sine?

**Always watch your signs.**

Comment: In "...where the wine value..." perhaps you meant "sine"?

Comment: Please correct this.  My device often auticorrects words to the wrong word and I cannot chase it down 100% of the time.  Thanks.

Comment: Um... don't worry. You can always edit your own posts.